# Clean install windows 10 and formatting

Tags: windows, windows-10, formatting, clean-install

I have a 1 TB hard Disk, divided into roughly equal sized local drives with labels C:,D:\ &E:( D &E for personal files and C for system files.)
During clean installation, under custom intsall, I'm not sure what I should select between "format" and "delete". I want to format my hard disk completely but I'm afraid whether clicking on "delete" would result in losing the predefined partitions(C,D,E) and I would end up with just a single local drive on"My computer" . I want to retain the above partitions of hard disk, removing all the files saved before.
Please help. This is the first time I'm performing a clean install myself.
Thanks.

Comment: Delete the partition you want to install w10 on, then it becomes unallocated, then select that partition and hit enter to start installation, it will be automatically formatted by the windows installer,.

Comment: If you want to perform a clean installation, is there a reason you are against using the Reset feature, and choosing the option not to keep your personal files?  Furthermore, you could simply launch Setup.exe from an installation media, and choose not to keep your personal files.  This is an excellent way, to avoid common avoidable mistakes, due to not understand what the "delete" option will do.  The best way to avoid data loss, is to perform a Reset from within Windows, this will only touch the system partition.

Comment: After Windows is reinstalled you can format your other partitions.

Comment: @Ramhound, I tried to reset which ran for some time like 33% after which it aborted. I tried running the setup.exe on installation media too but even that didn't work out.

Comment: @Jor_El - You will have to provide the failure reason from the log that was generated.  However, that really should be, it’s own question

Answer (score 3):

I feel the need to post an answer, as John's answer only partially answers your question. Moab is spot on, in the comments though.

When you install windows, you get the partition screen. If you want to have a clean drive but keep the partitions in check, you want to choose format, not delete. You can either perform the format of the D and E drives currently in windows using Disk Manager (see John's answer) or during the windows install. As for the C drive, given that Windows is currently using it, and formatting C would break windows, C is protected from accidental formatting, so you will want to format during the install process.

That said, I always remove the partition and select the empty unallocated space for my installation target. This will allow windows setup to create additional partitions, which are useful for troubleshooting.

So what you want to do in the Windows Installer is format the partitions of D and E if you want that still to happen during install and not prefer to do it before or after the install from within Windows.

During the Windows Install process, you want to delete the C partition and optionally other small partitions such as SYSTEM, BOOT, etc. Basically, delete all partitions except D and E. Now, select the unallocated space and instead of creating a new partition, just press next to install windows to that unallocated space. Windows will then create the new partitions automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Open Disk Management.  (My) Computer, right click, Manage, Disk Management.

Now see the partitions that are there - it will show you.

Right click on the specific partition you wish to format, select format and then format it.

**Note:**  Wherever data is combined in folders on a drive / partition you wish to format, back all that up first and then format. That works for any partition including the primary partition.

That should work and be safe to do. Back up any important data first to be certain.

[image]

Comment: You cannot do this for C, only D and E, so this answer is only half truth. It should explain how to perform the install more than formatting a drive... I'm not going to downvote the answer, but the answer needs some work.

Comment: Back up what is need (in my answer) and format the partition afterward

Comment: Yes, but you cannot format the C drive, and they want to reinstall. Nowhere in your answer does it tell how to do the install which IMHO is the primary part of the question.

Comment: I clarified my answer to assist the member

Comment: I see you now received a downvote. That was not from me, but I did post an answer. In my answer I referred to yours though, so if I can have any say in it, please keep it. I'll upvote your answer.